# Mobile website keeps zooming out when pop up menu is opened

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a mobile website and I am testing out the menu button right now. Whenever I click on it, the whole page zooms out but the pup up menu isn't big enough to fit the screen. I don't want the page to zoom out whenever the user clicks the menu button. How do I achieve this?

The first picture is when the menu is hidden and the screen is at 1.1x. The second picture is when the menu is displayed and the screen is at 1.0x.
[image: Website with menu hidden. Notice the screen is at 1.1x]

[image: Website with menu displayed. The screen is now at 1.0x]

Comment: I read your question twice and I understand nothing :D !

Comment: Sorry. Basically, the screen zooms out whenever I click on my menu button and I don't want that to happen. The menu isn't big enough to cover the screen so I dont know why it keeps zooming out. Is there a fix to this?

Comment: Is it that the screen is zooming out or that the page content is all being pushed to the left? I'm curious whether its actually using the CSS `zoom` or scaling the page, or just pushing things to look like its scaling

Comment: The weird thing is that sometimes it doesn't zoom and sometimes it does.  Aeolingamenfel, you have a very interesting point. I added in zoom:1.0; in my css but it's still "zooming" out.

Comment: The text is also smaller when the menu is displayed so I'm guessing it has to be css zoom but when I try to set it, it automatically zooms out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that view-port is setup correctly

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and make sure you use `zoom:1.1;` in css

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the viewport and changed my css to fix this problem.